# Set questions(discrete mathematics)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Let $A$, $B$ and $C$ be sets.
Prove or disprove (with a counter example) each of the following:

(a) If $A / C = B / C$ then $A = B$.

(b) If [($A \cap C = B \cap C)\&( A / C = B/ C)$] then $A = B$.

(c) If [$(A \cup C = B \cup C)\&(A / C = B / C)$] then $A = B$.

I understand why they are equal when I think about it visually in my head but how do I prove or disprove them formally? Like the steps required?

Comment: Do you define $A/C$ only for $C\subseteq A$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Hint*

For proving equality, apply the definitions:

> (i) $A \setminus C = B \setminus C$ **iff** $x \in A \setminus C \leftrightarrow x \in B \setminus C$, for any $x$

and :

> (ii) $x \in A \setminus C$ **iff** $x \in A$ and $x \notin C$.

*Note* : for $A \setminus C$, note that it is not necessary that the "subtracted" set (in this case : $C$) must be included into the other one ($A$).

---

To disprove them, you have to find some suitable counterexamples.